# The semantic of call/cc and "ensure" in Ruby

Tags: ruby, language-design, finally, callcc

As I know so far, Ruby is the only mainstream language that supports both `call/cc` and `try/catch/finally` (written as `begin/rescue/ensure/end` block).

I am not familiar with Ruby, but my intuitive tell me that there are potential conflicts of that two, since `call/cc` allows arbitrarily control flow and `ensure` require some guaranteed   control flow (some code path MUST be executed in a pre-defined situation, namely leaving the containing block).

So, are there any conflicts exists in the language? if so what is the defined behavior of the language in such a case? Especially, what happen if `call/cc` being used in a `begin/ensure` block or in the `ensure/end` block? What if calling a captured `call/cc` after the block contains `ensure` clause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ruby you have [`callcc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-callcc), [`throw`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-throw) / [`catch`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-catch) and [`raise`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-raise) / `rescue` / `ensure`.

`throw` terminates the block with `ensure` begin executed:

```
catch(:done) {
  begin
    puts "before"
    throw :done
    puts "after"  # will not be called
  ensure
    puts "ensure"
  end
}
```

produces:

```
before
ensure
```

---

`callcc` terminates the block with `ensure` begin skipped:

```
callcc { |cc|
  begin
    puts "before"
    cc.call
    puts "after"   # will not be called
  ensure
    puts "ensure"  # will not be called
  end
}
```

produces:

```
before
```

---

Another example storing the [`Continuation`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Continuation.html) object inside a global variable:

```
begin
  puts "before"
  callcc { |cc| $cc = cc }
  puts "after"
ensure
  puts "ensure"
end

$cc.call
```

produces:

```
before
after
ensure
after
ensure
after
...
```

Comment: OK, so what if I use `callcc` to jump into the `begin` block or even the `ensure` block?

Comment: You cannot jump to an arbitrary position, `cc.call` always jumps to the end of the `callcc { }` block.

Comment: I mean, what if I put a `callcc` block INSIDE the `begin/end` block, return a function (with the continuation variable) from inside, and then call that function from outside, to jump inside the block?

Comment: So the conclusion is, `callcc` has more priority than `ensure`, `ensure` can only ensure execution if there is no `callcc` exists.