# Is it make sense to make IO an instance of MonadCont?

Tags: haskell, monads, continuation

Obviously `MonadCont`s is more restricted and gives more power than plain `Monad`s, thanks to its `callCC`. This means less instances of it, and more you can do with it.

When look at defined instances of `MonadCont`, it looks like everything listed there require either `Cont` or `ContT` or an already existing `MonadCont` instance. That means we have to start with some `Cont` or `ContT` and in particular cannot turn `IO` into a `MonadCont`.

However, I believe it makes sense to use `callCC` in a `IO` context, so we can simplify the following (adjusted from the [official Hackage page](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.0.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Cont.html#g:6) `callCC` example):

```
whatsYourName :: IO ()
whatsYourName = do
    name <- getLine
    let response = flip runCont id $ do
        callCC $ \exit -> do
            when (null name) (exit "You forgot to tell me your name!")
            return $ "Welcome, " ++ name ++ "!"            
    print response
```

into

```
whatsYourName' :: IO ()
whatsYourName' = do
    name <- getLine
    response <- callCC $ \exit -> do
            when (null name) (exit "You forgot to tell me your name!")
            return $ "Welcome, " ++ name ++ "!"            
    print response
```

to use `callCC` in a do block in a cleaner way.

Of cause, to make `IO` an instance of `MonadCont` we must have some magic, since `callCC` for `IO` means "call the given function with the future computation specifies what to happen next in the real world", so only the interpreter or the compiler can actually know what this mean. On the other hand, I didn't see any theoretical reason that this is importable, since Scheme already have it for a long time, and making such an instance requires no language change at all.

**Possible issue**

One factor I can think of is that the semantic of `callCC` is conflict with proper cleanup guarantee. A lot of languages provides "try...finally" control for proper cleanup, and C++'s destructor is also garantee that. I am not sure what is it in Haskell, but if `callCC` is available for `IO` one can then use it to escape from any `IO` involved context that requires cleanup, so providing sush a garantee will become impossible, as you can see [what happens in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036367/the-semantic-of-call-cc-and-ensure-in-ruby).

**Discussion of opinions**

The answer from @jozefg is very good. I just want to write down my opinions here.

1. It is true that `MonadCont` come from mtl. But that does not means GHC or other compiler cannot define a `unsafeCallCC` and define the instance if `MonadCont` with the correct definition is in scope of the compiling module and `-XIOMonadCont` being set.
2. I already talked about exception safety and it looks hard to be sure about that. However, Haskell already have `unsafePerformIO`, which basically even more unsafe than `unsafeCallCC`, in my opinion.
3. Of cause `callCC` is, in most case, too powerful and should be avoid when possible. However, in my opinion, continuation passing style can be used to make lazy evaluation explicit, which can help better understand the program and thus easier to find possible optimizations. Of cause CPS is not `MonadCont`, but it is a natural step to use it and convert the deep nested inner functions into do notations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd say this is a bad idea. First of all, `MonadCont` is in the MTL. GHC has no knowledge about it, this would mean making the compiler depend on a 3rd party library, ick.

Second, `callCC` is unpopular even among some very high profile Schemers, mainly because it makes reasoning about the code a pain! In much the same way that `goto` is hard to reason about. Particularly when in Haskell where'd we'd have to concerns

1. Is it exception safe? (Which is pretty hard already)
2. Is it `callCC` safe?

Finally, we don't even need it. If you want to use continuations and IO, use `ContT IO`, it's exactly as powerful. However, I almost guarantee that it can be replaced with something less powerful, like `monad-prompt`. Continuations are a sledge-hammer, 9 out of 10 times, `callCC` is too powerful and can be more pleasantly phrased using a combination of higher order functions and laziness.

As an example, one of the prototypical uses of `callCC` is to implement something like exceptions, but in Haskell we can just use monads :) (which rely on higher order functions and laziness).

In essence what your proposing increases complexity, means merging the MTL into base, and a whole host of other unpleasantness to just avoid `liftIO`.

#### RE Edits

1. Sure you can do this, but then it's not an instance of `MonadCont` of course :)
2. This is a bit different, `unsafePerformIO` is meant to be used so that the side effects aren't visible to anyone else since you have no guarantees how or when things are executed.

   If this was the case with `callCCIO`, then you could just use `Cont`!
3. Continuation passing style is useful, and we have it, with `ConT r IO`! This is the biggest nail in the coffin for me, I don't see **any** benefit for this idea over just using the existing library over a difficult and potentially unsafe compiler hack.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, please have a look at my edit which responses your arguments.

Answer (score 1):

By using the `ContT` monad for simple abort functionality you are effectively hitting a fly with a bazooka.  :-) If your goal is just to abort returning an error message when something goes wrong, then you may want to consider using the `ErrorT` monad (provided by [transformers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Error.html)) instead.  Alternatively, if you will not be using a separate type for the result when an error occurs, then you may want to consider using the `AbortT` monad (provided by [AbortT-transformers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/AbortT-transformers/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Abort.html)) instead.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO because call/cc is a bad feature for any language. Although call/cc has been in Scheme for a very long time, it does not mean that call/cc is a good language feature. The experience with call/cc in Scheme showed that it is a bad language feature: using call/cc often leaks memory, call/cc without dynamic-wind is unsuitable for any serious program or any library; on the other hand, with dynamic-wind the standard call/cc idioms become slow. All these drawbacks are enumerated, with *supporting code* and other evidence, in
http://okmij.org/ftp/continuations/against-callcc.html

I agree that continuation-passing style has many benefits. In fact, when we write Haskell code in monadic style, we use exactly the CPS. Indeed, consider a simple nested function invocation `putChar (getChar ())`. We write it in CPS as follows

```
 getCharK :: () -> (Char -> w) -> w
 putCharK :: Char -> (() -> w) -> w

 gp :: (() -> w) -> w
 gp = \k -> getCharK () (\c -> putCharK c k)
```

And here how we write the same nested invocation for monadic getM and putM (for some monad M):

```
getM :: () -> M Char
putM :: Char -> M ()

gpM :: M ()
gpM =  getM () `bind` (\c -> putM c)
```

Now, if bind is defined as

```
bind m f = \k -> m (\x -> (f x) k)
```

then the monadic nested function application is identical to CPS version of the code.
The monadic example works in Haskell if you replace M with `ContT w IO` and and newtype
wrappers ContT/runContT in the definition of bind (which becomes `(>>=)` in the ContT w IO monad). So, Haskell already lets us write code in CPS; the do-nonation makes it quite convenient.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says:

> Many algorithms which require continuations in other languages do not
>   require them in Haskell, due to Haskell's lazy semantics. Abuse of the
>   Continuation monad can produce code that is impossible to understand
>   and maintain

I guess this is probably the *main* reason.